# Dropdown button holder issue

Tags: css

I'm having issues getting this button to stay in the button holder which floats above my site content. How would I add a drop down menu and this keep it in the same button holder.

```css
.btn-holder {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
position: static;
z-index: 10;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
.button {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color:  #a137a7;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 13px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: -1%;
  bottom: -1%;
  font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
opacity: .8; }

.button:hover {
    background-color: #732878; /* Green */
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-holder">
  <div class="button"><a href="/"><img class="img-responsive2"       
       src="http://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/e6Yod1iwo/pop-out-icon.png"></a></div>
</div>




<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: It appears to be working fine on my side?

Comment: This is the .CSS code I'm working with but without any drop down function from hovering over the button. This is what I'm asking, How am I able to implement this within the btn-holder, 

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Ok I'll create an example for you and post an answer.

Comment: That good be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example that should help get you started in the right direction! A few improvements could be made (such as delaying the `display:none` so that you can actually click links in the menu), but you should be able to figure that out. If not just let me know in the comments and I'll improve it.

```css
#btn-holder {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: static;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#btn-holder > .button {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #a137a7;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 13px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: -1%;
  bottom: -1%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  opacity: .8;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#btn-holder > .button:hover {
  background-color: #732878;
  color: white;
}

#btn-holder > .menu {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  width: 100px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #333;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 25px;
  box-shadow:0 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
  transition: color .3s;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #2196f3;
}

.menu > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.menu > ul > li:first-child {
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.menu p {
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu p:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    opacity: .4;
}

#btn-holder > .button:hover + .menu {
  opacity: 1;
  transistion-delay: 1s;
}

#btn-holder .menu:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn-holder">
  <div class="button">
    <a href="/"><img class="img-responsive2" src="https://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/e6Yod1iwo/pop-out-icon.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <p><a href="#">Home</a></p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Post 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Post 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p><a href="#">Products</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">About</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen of it that you can use to try your own changes on: http://codepen.io/XanderLuciano/pen/YGPoqE

I used the CSS `+` selector to select the `div class="menu"` that occurs right after the `div class="button"` and changed it's `display` from `none` to `block` when `.button:hover` is active. The code looks like this:

```
#btn-holder > .button:hover + .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions! :)

Comment: Unable to actually access the popup menu though.

Comment: That's where you'll have to mess with a transition and a delay and set it's `display:block` to hover as well.

Comment: @XanderLuciano   

Am I adding this transition delay correctly? I'm assuming this this will only work on some browsers. I'm unable to click a link when trying to select an item in the nav bar. 

`#btn-holder > .button:hover + .menu { display: block; transition-delay: 5s; }`

Comment: @troxie then add `.menu: hover {display: block;}` and you should be able to click the links.

Comment: @XanderLuciano You can see on my code pen how I've implemented `.menu: hover {display: block;}` http://codepen.io/seanjames/pen/xEGxxO

Comment: @troxie I updated the code example to do what you want

Comment: @XanderLuciano Thank you for your help.

Comment: @troxie no problem. Please accept my answer if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#btn-holder {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: static;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#btn-holder > .button {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #a137a7;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 13px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: -1%;
  bottom: -1%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  opacity: .8;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#btn-holder > .button:hover {
  background-color: #732878;
  color: white;
}

#btn-holder > .menu {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  width: 100px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #333;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 25px;
  box-shadow:0 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
  transition: color .3s;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #2196f3;
}

.menu > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.menu > ul > li:first-child {
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.menu p {
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu p:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    opacity: .4;
}

#btn-holder > .button:hover + .menu {
  opacity: 1;
  transistion-delay: 1s;
}

#btn-holder .menu:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn-holder">
  <div class="button">
    <a href="/"><img class="img-responsive2" src="https://static.tumblr.com/e2rgcy1/e6Yod1iwo/pop-out-icon.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <p><a href="#">Home</a></p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Post 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Post 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p><a href="#">Products</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">About</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```